# How to authenticate google-vision api credentials on heroku using node.js?

Tags: node.js, heroku, google-vision

I am running a Node.js application on localhost, which uses Google Vision API to process an image. I am able to authenticate the API locally by providing the path to the .json file, however when I deploy my application to Heroku, it fails to process the API call and I am assuming the reason behind this would be that it is failing API authentication. How can I authenticate the Google-Vision API on Heroku using the .json file provided by google cloud?

Comment: Do you have any logs you can share? Did you put the json file on your server?

Comment: I figured out how to authenticate using https://github.com/elishaterada/heroku-google-application-credentials-buildpack, but now when I send a POST request to my application it gives an H13 error as follows (attaching the screenshot of logs here)- https://i.stack.imgur.com/QByZ4.png. What might be causing this error?

 I am extracting text from image using google-vision API and then sending a POST request to my webpage to display the extracted data in a form. It works sometimes with only selected images, however, in general for most of the images it doesn't work and gives me the H13 error.

Comment: Here is what heroku says about H13 error: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h13-connection-closed-without-response .  If you have 1 image that always works and 1 image that never works, try calling vision api directly (no heroku) and compare the responses of the 2 images to see if anything jumps out as different with respect to how you are processing those responses.

Comment: I compared the two images- the one which work usually have a size of about (150-200 KB), and the ones which don't are usually more than 200KB, so I compressed the size of all images to 150-200 KB range. However, it still doesn't seem to work for those images even after compressing. I noticed one other difference was that the extension for those working images were '.JPG', however the ones which weren't working were '.jpg'.

Comment: I noticed '.JPG' image it sends the response within the response time and redirects to the right page, however with '.jpg' images I can see the response after the app crashed and when I send the form again, so is it a timeout issue?

Comment: If you use curl or just a small python script to call the api, do you notice any difference? Probably good to remove heroku from picture to figure out what the difference is between your 2 sets of images.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If anyone is still looking for this answer, without installing any additional npm package,  I solve the authentication issue by checking https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars and setting it in my app this way:

1. place the .json file in the root directory of the app, then deploy it to heroku
2. Go to settings in your heroku app and set a new CONFIG VARIABLE  like this:

   key : GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS

   value: MYCREDENTIALS.json

**** note the name of the file has no quotes (""), click add and it should work.

Comment: Please do not recommend committing `.json` to git. It is a security risk. Use custom built pack specifically created to address this. (Refer to Ian Bell's comment - which has link to the build pack)
I wrote about it here : https://learnings.desipenguin.com/post/goog-cred-heroku/